# Can you link an audio track to a video track in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

I am editing a video in iMovie. The video file is independent of the audio file; the video file's audio is what the camera picked up, and the audio file is what our lav mic picked up. After carefully listening/watching to the two tracks, I now have them synced in iMovie. **Is there a way to link the two together so they act as one audio/video file in the timeline?** Right now I'm exporting it as a movie file to re-import in as one file, but I hope there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

Nope! There's no simpler way. I'm running into the same problem right now, and it's very annoying! That's why I'm considering getting Premiere Pro or Final Cut X. It's silly to try to do any major editing in iMovie.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it is more work. You have to add the audio in another project and export in and reimport it or add it in other software. It is pointless. Just like Devin, get a better pice of software. If you want you can try Motion for 50 bucks on the Mac App Store.